# Whats the easiest way to setup a local subversion server?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm really not well versed in these things, I just want to setup an svn server locally on my computer. Also I'd like to set it up and integrate it directly into Visual Studio 2008 if it's possible?

thanks for any help!

Comment: why would you want to setup a local server?  I highly highly recommend you use cvsdude and have someone else host.  That way if your drive crashes you don't lose your work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I used TortoiseSVN, created a directory (C:\Repositories) then used the menu command "Create Repository Here...".

Comment: +1 — I've used TortoiseSVN for a couple of years now and no idea it could do that! :-)

Comment: Be aware that if you ever grant access to another user and you both access (write to) the repository at the same time, you could corrupt one or more files when using file based repositories. It doesn't happen often, but it is hard to figure out why the files get corrupted.

Server based repositories don't have that problem.

Answer (score 8):

Just create a local svn repository and use a file:// based urls for them source code. Shouldn't need to have a specific. running, server instance for this.

Comment: You save my day =) Thank you so mutch!

Answer (score 8):

I would second Visual SVN server which is free and will have you up and running in a few minutes. It hooks up SVN over HTTP however and for a local Subversion installation that might not be necesary.

If you'd rather run just setup Subversion 'manualy' the following is a walk through of the process with focus on Visual Studio usage:
http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/subversion/

Answer (score 6):

Check for http://www.visualsvn.com/ for the server and TortoiseSVN for the client.
Check for AnkhSVN for integration with Visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.visualsvn.com/  That should help with your integration issues

Answer (score 4):

Rick Strahl, FTW!

Another great walk-through on setting up SVN with Windows comes from Jeff Atwood of Coding Horror:

[Setting up Subversion on Windows](https://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/)

In a nutshell:

1. Download/Install SVN, configure as windows service
2. Install TortoiseSVN (or your SVN GUI of choice). I recommend sticking with Tortoise, since there have been anecdotal horror stories of using SVN clients integrated with VS
3. Create a repository (either through CLI or GUI client

Comment: I don't think recommending against VS integration helps. It's painful to manually deal with renames and moves, especially when doing refactoring (because that renames the files on disk without performing svn rename).

Comment: True it is a PITA - we use Tortoise SVN w/o VS integration at my shop - but we tried to use VS integration and some people had huge problems with checking files in/out, merging, etc... maybe they were using an inferior client, but because of those problems is why I'm cautioning against it

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) as a local host for the files with tortoise [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)  for browse integration or/and [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for intergration with vs2008.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Toirtoise SVN its fairly easy to setup and use.

Here is the [documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html), its a must!