# Subversion windows server

Tags: svn, version-control

I've been using TortoiseSVN for a while now for a few of my side projects, but for the hosting I always used some other companies.

Now the time has come when at the company where I work, we start experimenting with it and I'd need a few pointers, regarding how to install a svn server.
I came accross [link text](http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/) and [link text](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/doc/server-config/) but I'm a bit unsure which one's the way to go, or if there's any difference between the two of them. ( My only worry about the visualSVN one is that it inccludes an Apache server if I'm right, which might cause problems for us, as we use the server we're going to install svn onto for other purposes too, including hosting sites using IIS )
Also, being able to access the repository through the web is not important for us as we'll mainly access it through the local network.

So any recommendations which one to install?

cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859577/whats-the-easiest-way-to-setup-a-local-subversion-server/

Comment: in that post it's about setting up the server on the same machine, which is I guess slightly different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used VisualSVN and it is very simple to setup and manage.  If I remember correctly, you don't need to configure or do much setup with Apache if you're not going to use it for web access.  I have not heard of SVN1Click, but that just seems like a way to get you up and running.

Another install you may want to look at is [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/).  Not quite as straightforward as VisualSVN, but it is well known and I have used it and have been happy with it.

My best advice would be - download them and try them out for a bit (before deploying out to your company) and have some of your developers try it out (on a test-basis only) and determine if the server meets your company's needs.

Comment: Cheers Jason, I think that's what I'll do, but I wanted to make sure I'm not completely off the track.

Comment: Here we tested them in virtual machines. Makes it easier to switch from one test installation to the next, go back to certain saved states, etc.

Comment: Note that SVN1Click seems to be pretty dead.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) for almost a year, and it works great.
It's very simple to install and configure (next-next-next).

It's your best choice.

Comment: +1 -- Agreed. This is what I was going to post. I've been using VisualSVN server since it's initial public release. It works great. But you will want to learn about svnadmin

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [original](http://subversion.tigris.org/) Subversion server - binaries are available [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100). To the best of my knowledge, enabling access via Apache is optional. Without Apache, you can access the repositories using TortoiseSVN and the svn:// protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Apache and IIS can co-exist on the same server.  (They do now on our server.)  You just need to configure them for two different ports.  In our case, IIS (which powers our Wiki and Issue Tracker) is on port 80, and the Apache-SVN instance is on port 8080.

You could also do the SvnServe route, which offers better performance, but it has some drawbacks.  (LDAP authentication is harder to do, can't use WebDAV to do auto-versioning, can read the repo with standard HTTP.)  It all depends on what you need for your setup.

We use the CollabNet server.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Collabnet Subversion](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/getit.html) at our company. The installation is matter of Next->Next->Next and it setups the necessary services for you (svnserve or Apache w/ WebDAV). We use only svnserve though.

You may need to enable the port 3690 (SvnServe) on the firewall.

Comment: That said, VisualSVN is as easy to install as the Collabnet one.

Comment: Huh...I remember CollabNet being more difficult to install than VisualSVN.  Glad to hear that it's not.